# Spring to use fully qualified names for constructor dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

I have multiple modules (application + library) in a project and they contain service classes of same names (but different packages) that are to be injected thru Lombok generated constructors within their respective modules.
When I start the app module, the Spring's `ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner` however picks both and raises `BeanDefinitionStoreException` because it detects both as a candidates, due to the same bean name and doesn't care about the fully qualified type name.
Is there an option to enable more precise resolution of the beans that also requires a type match?
Isn't this a design flaw? What am I missing?

Edit: Names, I believe, are taken from constructors generated by Lombok's @RequiredArgsConstructor, and service classes are also generated code (MapStruct mappers).

[image]

Comment: Did you tried adding custom name to the bean?

Comment: Names, I believe, are taken from constructors generated by Lombok's @RequiredArgsConstructor, and service classes are also generated code (MapStruct mappers). I don't know any way of changing them

Comment: as explained in the spring documentation the default for names is the classname with a lower cased letter. You can specify a different strategy by passing in a `BeanNameGenerator` which does this. Spring ships with one out of the box you could use, which is aptly named, `FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Component("beanName")`, `@Bean("beanName")`, `@Named("beanName")` to assign a custom name to a bean. By default, spring uses the class name as the bean name. For Example, you can define bean name of your CustomAccountsApiController class as below:

```
@RestController("customAccountsApiControllerPrimary")
public class CustomAccountsApiController {
    
}
```

You can read more on bean name from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-names)